# Can computers recognise "grouping" from voice tonality?

Tags: natural-language-processing, voice-recognition, speech-synthesis

In human communication, tonality or tonal language play many complex information, including emotions and motives. But excluding such complex aspects, tonality serves some a very basic purpose of "grouping" or "taking common" functions such as:

1. The sweet, (pause), bread-and-drink.

It means "The sweet bread and the sweet drink". However

2. The sweet-bread, (pause) and drink.

It means only the bread is sweet but the drink isn't necessarily sweet, or the drink's sweetness property isn't assigned.

Can computers recognise these differences of meaning based on tonality?